# Appending the contents of a file at the beginning of another file in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I know that

```
cat file1 >> file2
```

would append the contents of file1 at the end of file2. On the other hand, how can I append the contents of file1 at the beginning of file 2, and not at its end?

Actually, i have a single master file M, and several other files in a directory D. I want to append the contents of file M at the beginning of all the files in the directory D.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each file you could do:

```
cat MASTER file >> file.tmp
```

And then move file.tmp over file.

Answer (score 10):

Just do:

```
cat file1 file2 > tmp && mv tmp file2
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use a temporary file and rename it after merge.

Example:

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc" > LETTERS
echo -e "1\n2\n3" > NUMBERS 
cat NUMBERS LETTERS > TMP
mv TMP LETTERS
cat LETTERS
```

Your command might look something like:

```
for file in $( find -name "*.java" ); do cat PREPEND ${file} > ${file}.tmp; mv ${file}.tmp ${file}; done
```